# How to solve incorrect RAM reading MS-7529 Motherboard, 8GB RAM

Tags: ram

My desktop computer was using 2 x 1GB (2GB) RAM, DDR2  and I have recently replaced the 1 GB modules with 2 x 4GB modules to give me a total of 8GB. The motherboard is MS-7529 and I upgraded the BIOS to the latest version but the system reads the modules as 512MB giving me a total of 1GB. The same maximum RAM is shown when I use Windows 10 X-64 or Ubuntu 20.0 X-64 Operating systems. What do I need to do to get the system recognize the full 8GB RAM? The specs for the MS-7529 Motherboard says the maximum RAM is 8GB. The processor is Intel dual core E-3300 @ 2.5GH.

Answer (score 0):

Check the speed Limitations accepted by the motherboard. You can refer to this [link](https://www.game-debate.com/motherboard/index.php?mot_id=3266) .